# Disable datepicking in form2 based on form1 selected date bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm currently using this awesome bootstrap-datetimepicker from (http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). How to disable date on form2 based on form1 selected date??

here is my current javascript for the datetimepicker

```
    $('.bookingfrom').datetimepicker({
            language:  'en',
            weekStart: 1,
            todayBtn:  1,
            autoclose: 1,
            todayHighlight: 1,
            startView: 2,
            minView: 2,
            startDate: '+0d',
            forceParse: 0
        });
    $('.bookinguntil').datetimepicker({
            language:  'en',
            weekStart: 1,
            todayBtn:  1,
            autoclose: 1,
            todayHighlight: 1,
            startView: 2,
            minView: 2,
            startDate: '+0d',
            forceParse: 0
        });
```

I found 1 function on the documentation that I think can do the work. I just dont know how.

```
  $('#date-end')
 .datetimepicker()
 .on('changeDate', function(ev){
     if (ev.date.valueOf() < date-start-display.valueOf()){
         ....
        }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

i've used it like this

```html
  //Set the date picker on the text boxes for Check Out Date
            $(".checkOutDate").datetimepicker({
                format: "dd M yyyy",
                autoclose: true,
                showMeridian: true,
                startDate: minDateForCheckIn
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                //Parse the selected date string to date object.
                var dateSelected = new Date(Date.parse(ev.date));
                //Subtract 5 hours and 35 minutes (extra 5 minutes to prevent selection of same time in check in field) to adjust GMT timings.
                dateSelected.setHours(dateSelected.getHours() +24, 0, 0, 0);
                $(".checkInDate").datetimepicker('setEndDate', dateSelected);
            });

            //Set the date picker on the text boxes for Check In Date. [Once the check in date is selected, set the selected date as min date for check out]
            $(".checkInDate").datetimepicker({
                format: "dd M yyyy",
                autoclose: true,
                showMeridian: true,
                startDate: minDateForCheckIn
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                //Parse the selected date string to date object.
                var dateSelected = new Date(Date.parse(ev.date));
                //Subtract 5 hours and 25 minutes (less 5 minutes to prevent selection of same time in check out field) to adjust GMT timings.
                dateSelected.setHours(dateSelected.getHours() + 24, 0, 0, 0);
                $(".checkOutDate").datetimepicker('setStartDate', dateSelected);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but this is definitely possible. I see you are also trying to disable dates before the current day. I've come up with the following solution that does exactly as asked:

First you need to initialise the `minDate` parameter to midnight of the current day. Then, you bind an event listener to the `dp.change` event and reject any times that are *earlier* than the current time.
When rejecting such a time, you notify the user and reset the DateTimePicker time to the current time. I've created a function to do this:

```
// Argument obj is the used DateTimePicker object
// Argument f is the selected datetime by the user
// Argument n is the current datetime
var checkDate = function (obj, f, n) {
    if (f.getTime() < n.getTime()+60*1000 && !open) {
        open = true;
        $('#message').dialog({
            modal: true,
            position: ['center', 'center'],
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            width: 400,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            buttons: {
                "I understand. Let me try again": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    obj.data('DateTimePicker').setDate(n);
                    open = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Likewise, you still want to update the `minDate` and `maxDate` parameters upon `dp.change` too. Therefore, combining both checking the time and updating the properties, you would get:

```
jQuery("#startDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var f = new Date(e.date);    var n = new Date();
    checkDate(jQuery('#startDate'), f, n);
    jQuery('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
});
jQuery("#endDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var f = new Date(e.date);    var n = new Date();
    checkDate(jQuery('#startDate'), f, n);
    jQuery('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
});
```

This will yield exactly what you are after:

[image]

You can find the full code in this jsFiddle:

## [GO TO THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uuo4rshj/)